# How to make a sprite blinking for sometime-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

How can I make a sprite blink for some time?

In my game I have a house sprite.Initially it is a bright one.Once another sprite touches this house,light inside the house will start blinking.Like turning light ON and OFF continuously.

I tried different ways.I couldn't make it work.
Hope someone will share their idea to do this.

Comment: Are you using box2d light ?

Comment: No.Scene2d only.@AbhishekAryan

Comment: Then what do you mean by light here ?

Comment: I was just telling about the game event I want to make.Blinking of light.Here light is just a real word thing.Not related to Box2d.I am using images only.I am looking for an idea to make a sprite blink@AbhishekAryan

Comment: when you say sprite blinking you mean it will appear then disappear then appear and so on?

Comment: yes.@LorenceHernandez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two identical Texture one with glow and another without glow.
Achieve your requirement by just creating two image.

You're using scene2d so you can create two like image and image1;

```
SequenceAction actions=Actions.sequence(Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                image.setVisible(true);
                image1.setVisible(false);
            }
        }),Actions.delay(.2f),Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                image.setVisible(false);
                image1.setVisible(true);
            }
        }),Actions.delay(.2f));

Action myAction=Actions.forever(actions);  //or not forever
Action myAction=Actions.repeat(5,actions);

stage.addAction(myAction);
```

But this is not a good way, if you aware with `Shader` then use Shader Program here for your requirement.

Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkyGTZ0992s) and [tutorial](http://www.alcove-games.com/opengl-es-2-tutorials/lightmap-shader-fire-effect-glsl/) for the same. It is better option in my suggestion.

You can also used [box2dlight](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
long timeTracker = TimeUtils.millis();
long timeIntervalPerBlink = 50; // in ms
bool onOrOff = true; // if true light will on, else off
```

and then in update part you do this:

```
if ( TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(timeTracker) >= timeIntervalPerBlink )
{
    if ( onOrOff )
    {
        // turn on your light (draw it)
        onOrOff = !onOrOff;  // flip it, so in the next interval the light will be off if its on or on if its off.
        timeTracker = TimeUtils.millis(); //reset the time
    }
}
```